# Нужно получить данные с cbr.ru по курсам за определенный период

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, xmlparser

Я совсем новичок, хотела бы разобрать как же получить данные с сайта cbr.ru по курсам доллара и евро за 05.10.2018 - 10.10.2018.
Смотрела [здесь](https://www.cbr.ru/development/SXML/), но для себя нужного не нашла(
Хотелось бы путем через pandas python
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция чтения XML работает начиная с версии `Pandas 1.3.0`. По примеру из вашей ссылки читаем курс доллара за последние 10 дней:

```
#!pip install pandas==1.3.5
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=10/01/2022&date_req2=20/01/2022&VAL_NM_RQ=R01235'
pd.read_xml(url)
```

Вывод:

```
    Date        Id      Nominal Value
0   11.01.2022  R01235  1       75,1315
1   12.01.2022  R01235  1       74,8355
2   13.01.2022  R01235  1       74,5277
3   14.01.2022  R01235  1       74,5686
4   15.01.2022  R01235  1       75,7668
5   18.01.2022  R01235  1       76,0404
6   19.01.2022  R01235  1       76,3347
7   20.01.2022  R01235  1       76,8697
```

А также получаем все коды валют и котировки на сегодня:

```
url1 = 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=20/01/2022'
pd.read_xml(url1, encoding='cp1251')
```

Вывод (выравнивать не буду):

```
    ID  NumCode CharCode    Nominal Name    Value
0   R01010  36  AUD 1   Австралийский доллар    55,2078
1   R01020A 944 AZN 1   Азербайджанский манат   45,2441
2   R01035  826 GBP 1   Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства    104,4813
3   R01060  51  AMD 100 Армянских драмов    15,9912
4   R01090B 933 BYN 1   Белорусский рубль   29,5823
5   R01100  975 BGN 1   Болгарский лев  44,5363
6   R01115  986 BRL 1   Бразильский реал    13,8079
7   R01135  348 HUF 100 Венгерских форинтов 24,3382
8   R01200  344 HKD 10  Гонконгских долларов    98,6521
9   R01215  208 DKK 1   Датская крона   11,7042
10  R01235  840 USD 1   Доллар США  76,8697
11  R01239  978 EUR 1   Евро    87,1318
12  R01270  356 INR 10  Индийских рупий 10,3020
13  R01335  398 KZT 100 Казахстанских тенге 17,5964
14  R01350  124 CAD 1   Канадский доллар    61,4564
15  R01370  417 KGS 100 Киргизских сомов    90,6315
16  R01375  156 CNY 1   Китайский юань  12,1011
17  R01500  498 MDL 10  Молдавских леев 42,5871
18  R01535  578 NOK 10  Норвежских крон 87,3887
19  R01565  985 PLN 1   Польский злотый 19,1848
20  R01585F 946 RON 1   Румынский лей   17,6173
21  R01589  960 XDR 1   СДР (специальные права заимствования)   107,8943
22  R01625  702 SGD 1   Сингапурский доллар 56,9237
23  R01670  972 TJS 10  Таджикских сомони   68,0564
24  R01700J 949 TRY 10  Турецких лир    56,4318
25  R01710A 934 TMT 1   Новый туркменский манат 21,9942
26  R01717  860 UZS 10000   Узбекских сумов 71,0569
27  R01720  980 UAH 10  Украинских гривен   27,0835
28  R01760  203 CZK 10  Чешских крон    35,7251
29  R01770  752 SEK 10  Шведских крон   84,0942
30  R01775  756 CHF 1   Швейцарский франк   83,9280
31  R01810  710 ZAR 10  Южноафриканских рэндов  49,7185
32  R01815  410 KRW 1000    Вон Республики Корея    64,4672
33  R01820  392 JPY 100 Японских иен    67,1967
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное